# attribute of type java.time.LocalDateTime doesn't work as a JPA query parameter in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-8, jpql

I have an JPA entity with an attribute of type `java.time.LocalDateTime`. I use a `javax.persistence.Converter` annotation for this to work. I can load the entity and save it without problems, but when I try to execute a jpql query like this:

```
TypedQuery<Event> q = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT e " +
    "FROM Event e " +
    "WHERE :currentDateTime >= e.startDateTime", Event.class);
q.setParameter("currentDateTime", LocalDateTime.now().withSecond(0).withNano(0));
```

I get an error like this:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bytea >= timestamp without time zone
```

I've tried many things but couldn't get the parameter to work. I even tried to use `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` as the parameter but it also doesn't work.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3672/gbwlh/index.html

Comment: Sorry. Didn't get your point.

Comment: check in which SQL type transfered Java class and use correct java class instead of using LocalDateTime.

Comment: In my jpa converter, I convert LocalDateTime to `java.util.Date`. As you suggested I changed the parameter to a `java.util.Date`. The call now is like this: `q.setParameter("currentDateTime", new Date(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`, but now I get the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Tue May 19 10:07:00 BRT 2015] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (TIMESTAMP)]`. This is getting complicated.

Comment: It seems that there's an incoherence in JPA. It lets you have an attribute of any type in your entities, but doesn't let you use an attribute of that type in your queries. This is a very important issue, and I think that not only for me. If someone knows how to solve this, I would be very grateful. I'm stuck with this right now.

Comment: We use `java.util.Date` in JPA and `java.time.LocalDateTime` when to calculate with dates but convert from/to `java.util.Date` when needed to persist.

Comment: @Smutje but I want to use `java.time.LocalDateTime` directly in my entities as we have converters in JPA. Not only to manipulate dates. I want all my application to get rid of the legacy dates in Java. JPA should be smart enough to use the same converter that we use in the entity in the query parameters or something like this.

Comment: There is no incoherence in *JPA*. I use a JPQL implementation that supports such a query as that, just that it isn't Hibernate. Your experience is specific to how your implementation supports it, not to JPA itself

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought that all JPA providers have the same issue. For the time being I just can't change from Hibernate to another provider. What's the JPA provider you use? Do you know any workaround for my case?

Comment: @NeilStockton So, can you tell me which JPA provider you use and if you have any suggestions for the problem with Hibernate?

Comment: I use DataNucleus JPA, which has builtin support for java 8 time types, so no need for converters. Long time since I used Hibernate so can't help on that side

Comment: According to your answer, I still see that JPA has an incoherence. It seems that DataNucleus JPA added support to java 8 types by its own. Its a proprietary feature of DataNucleus, not of the standard current JPA specification. It just seems reasonable, though, that if the current JPA specification supports converters, the types would also work in JPQL queries. Maybe there's still a way to achieve this using Hibernate as a provider.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen in the comment that you want to query Timestamp

```
q.setParameter("currentDateTime", new Date(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

So your converter must be `LocalDateTime`⇔`Timestamp`

I've done this with Hibernate as a JPA provider, and my code looks like this in my `AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp>`

```
@Override
public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime date) {
    if (date == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return Timestamp.valueOf(date);
    }
}

@Override
public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return value.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```